# Oughtn't option premiums increase by the same amount as strike prices?

Tags: asset-pricing

1. Pls see this question's title. In the screenshot below, as the strike prices below increase by  +1, oughtn't the option premiums increase by +1 too?
2. Why buy the \$104 put  for \$13.71? The \$105 put looks more attractive to me; it has lower IV and costs only 4 cents more!

[image]

Comment: Volume of 0 and no bid or ask prices and minimal open interest suggests low liquidity so those "last" prices may have happened at very different times

Comment: The above comment by Henry appears to be the correct answer. You would need to compare bid/offer, or at least a close.